# Showing the whole process of GCD in Java

Tags: java

I'm not that new with Java (studied it years ago but stopped for 5-6 years because of work) and I'm trying to get in touch with it again. A friend of mine gave me practice problems I could work with to practice, but it is quite hard for me. It is basically showing the steps in finding GCD using Euclidean Algorithm. I did everything, but the last detail needed for the GCD is missing once I input a big number.

Here is the code I've done so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class mpONE {
   public static void main (String[] args) 
   {
      System.out.println("Finding GCD Using Euclid's Algorithm");
      Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your first (higher) number: ");
      int n1 = num.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter your second (lower) number: ");
      int n2 = num.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Numbers for finding GCD are: " + n1 + " " + n2);
      System.out.println("Computing for GCD... ");

      for (int i = 0; i <= n2; i++)
      {
         int g = n1/n2;
         int f = (g * n2);
         int h = n1 - f;
         System.out.print(n1 + " = " + "(" + n2 + " * " + g + ") + " + h);
         n1 = n2;
         n2 = h;
         System.out.println();
         if (h == 0)
         {
            break;
         }
     }

     for (int i = 1; i <= n1 && i <= n2; ++i) {
         if (n1 % i == 0 && n2 % i == 0)
         {
            int ans = i;
            System.out.println("Your GCD is " + ans);
         }
      }   
    } 
 }
```

With smaller numbers, it does work (the "+ h" should be 0), but with big numbers, it stops just before it shows the 0 remainder. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the location of the `if(h==0)` block:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class mpONE {
   public static void main (String[] args) 
   {
      System.out.println("Finding GCD Using Euclid's Algorithm");
      Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your first (higher) number: ");
      int n1 = num.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter your second (lower) number: ");
      int n2 = num.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Numbers for finding GCD are: " + n1 + " " + n2);
      System.out.println("Computing for GCD... ");

      for (int i = 0; i <= n2; i++)
      {
         int g = n1/n2;
         int f = (g * n2);
         int h = n1 - f;
         System.out.print(n1 + " = " + "(" + n2 + " * " + g + ") + " + h);
         System.out.println();
         if (h == 0)
         {
            break;
         }
         n1 = n2;
         n2 = h;
     }

     for (int i = 1; i <= n1 && i <= n2; ++i) {
         if (n1 % i == 0 && n2 % i == 0)
         {
            int ans = i;
            System.out.println("Your GCD is " + ans);
         }
      }   
    } 
 }
```